# Электрический и электронный

Tags: значение-слов, однокоренные-слова

Здравствуйте.
Извините за глупый вопрос, но подскажите, пожалуйста, как объяснить разницу между понятиями "электрический" и "электронный". И существенна ли она?
Спасибо

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Под "электрическим" понимают всё что относится к электричеству вообще и электрике в частности, а под "электронным" - к электронике. Электроника по сути та же электрика, но на микроуровне. Электрику нужно разбираться в проводах, а электронщику - в микросхемах.

"Электронный" ещё может относится к части атома, но это уже частное значение.

Answer (score 2):

В древней Греции "электроном" называлась смола, янтарь, который если потереть, нагревался, и начиналось движение элементарных частиц. Это слово и стало родоночальным "электричеству".
Сейчас "электричество" - это явление, энергия, движение и взаимодействие заряженных частиц.
А электрон - это элементарная частица с наименьшим отрицательным электрическим зарядом, электроника - наука об электронах. Следовательно, электрический - связанный с явлением, а электронный - с частицами.

Answer (score 2):

Относятся к родственным физическим явлениям, но на разном уровне развития физики.
"Электрический" — слово 19-го века (второй половины?), "электронный" — 20-го в.
тот случай, когда принцип работы физического прибора отражается в языке.

Вероятно, была потребность противопоставлять приборы новейшие ("электронные") прежним, электрическим.